# Use Spring Zuul on appengine

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, netflix-zuul

I would like to use Spring Zuul on App Engine like an API Gateway,
My applications will be like this:

[image]

I think that Zuul it is a good option for build an API Gateway.
Are there any problems in using Spring Zuul to do it in App Engine?

Comment: I would like to do the same. Did you try this?! If yes, how is it and if not what where the problems on achieving this?

Comment: I did some tests using a simple application and worked, but I did not use in my production application. I think that I need to do more test to use in a production environment.